# how to test if a string is a valid UTF16 string?

Tags: javascript, encoding, mongodb

I am using mongodb and javascript to do some string processing. Now I got some error like:

> `Sun May 23 07:42:20   Assertion failure JS_EncodeCharacters( _context , s , srclen , dst , &len) scripting/engine_spidermonkey.cpp 152
>
>   0x80f4f7e 0x80f8794 0x811525b 0x811a953 0x8119fc4 0x8111bc5 0x81b408e 0x81c4ee7 0x81b4a10 0x817a881 0x817a7d8 0x817a6e2 0x811e1bb 0x80a777b 0x80a8f8a 0xb7cb2455 0x80a37a1
>
>    mongodb-linux-i686-1.4.2/bin/mongo(_ZN5mongo12sayDbContextEPKc+0xfe) [0x80f4f7e]`

After doing some google, I find that JS_EncodeCharacters return false if the input is not a valid UTF16 string. (if spidermonkey is build with UTF-8 enabled)

So I was wondering how to test if the input string if a proper UTF16 string? so I can skip such kind of string to avoid problem ...

Thanks

Comment: Although https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16868415/encodeuricomponent-throws-an-exception is newer, maybe this question should be marked as duplicate, because that other question tells how to validate UTF-16 (`encodeURIComponent` throws if invalid) and answers how to sanitize.

Answer (score 2):

[This part of the UTF-16 FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-7) describes the sequences of invalid characters:

> The two values FFFE<sub>16</sub> and FFFF<sub>16</sub> as well as the 32 values from FDD0<sub>16</sub> to FDEF<sub>16</sub> represent noncharacters. They are invalid in interchange, but may be freely used internal to an implementation. Unpaired surrogates are invalid as well, i.e. any value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub> not followed by a value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub>, or any value in the range DC00<sub>16</sub> to DFFF<sub>16</sub> not preceded by a value in the range D800<sub>16</sub> to DBFF<sub>16</sub>.

If you're doing this in Javascript, I'm not sure it'll be all that easy to test for this, though...

Comment: Yeah .... That should be a way ... but seems a little hard :)

hopefully there is simpler way to do that ...

Answer (score 1):

The `String.prototype.isWellFormed()` method returns a boolean indicating whether the string does not contain any *lone (unmatched) surrogates*.